# Update breaks Drush

Tags: drush

When running `composer update` on the latest Drupal 8.4 rc1 Drush breaks.

I get the following error:

\Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\Array is not a valid Fqsen.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does this break during the update (when composer is running), or does drush output this after the update? Did you also update drush to version 9? [Drush 8 does not support drupal 8.4](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/).

Comment: Yupp. I had drush 9 installed. But I had to completely redo my vagrant machine.
I also added drush9 to the composer requirements together with installing webflo/drush-shim onto vagrant.

Seems to work.

Comment: I'm still getting this, even using the most recent version of drush... did you ever figure out what the actual cause was?

Comment: It seems that drush 8.1 and 9 beta had been installed at the same time... 

Try to remove all of 8.1 and use webflo/drush-shim.

drush_launcher_version: "0.3.1"
drush_phar_url: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/{{ drush_launcher_version }}/drush.phar

... in Drupal 8's composer.js say:
 "require": {
        "drush/drush": "^9.0",

... and make an update.

Works with me.